# How I Can Create A Launcher For a Program

Tags: firefox, launcher

As you know, Firefox has been update to 57.00 but some extensions doesen't work for me. For that i want to pass 56.00 and i remove Firefox 57.00, after that i download Firefox 56.00 version and lastly i copy Firefox 56.00 folder, to there **/usr/local directory**.

When i give the firefox command, on command line it's work, Firefox open but there is a no icon launcher.

When i search the Firefox starter icon, i can't found anything.

Now how i can create a launcher for Firefox?

PS: I am not using Unity, i'm using XFCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file in `/home/$USER/.local/share/applications/firefox-custom.desktop`, and add the follow lines of code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Firefox Quantum Edition
Icon=/path/to/mozicon128.png
Exec=/path/to/executable/firefox %u
Comment=Firefox Custom 56
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
```

With this when you search for it in `dash` you will see two launchers on for the `57` version in `/usr/bin/firefox` and the other for `56` custom in `/usr/local`

**Note (confirm and adjust accordingly):**

- Icon location would be: `/usr/local/firefox/browser/icons`
- Executable location would be: `/usr/local/firefox`

Comment: When i search, i only see icon for 57. Is i need to restart my computer?

Comment: yes please do so!

Comment: Hi George, i restart but this time when i click, i take a error like this.  Failed to execute, command "PATH-TO-FIREFOX.SH %f".

Comment: This `"PATH-TO-FIREFOX.SH %f` is just a **placeholder** it should contain the real path to your firefox executable like `/home/<your_username>/firefox/firefox %u`

Comment: It doesen't work again, i add my username but there is a no folder firefox on my username folder.

Comment: what is the path to that firefox 56 folder?

Comment: /usr/local directory

Comment: I solve the problem. I just change the Exec option like that Exec=firefox %u